# WebStorm auto-formatting adds leading whitespace to SQL template literals

Tags: javascript, typescript, webstorm

When auto-formatting injected `SQL` code in a template literal in `TypeScript`/`JavaScript`, `WebStorm` automatically adds leading whitespace to align each line to the declaration line, i.e.

```
        const query = `
          select field1         as x,
                 field123456789 as y,
          from mytable
        `;
```

instead of the preferred

```
        const query = `
select field1         as x,
       field123456789 as y,
from mytable
`;
```

This causes unnecessary whitespace in the string, especially when the declaration line itself is indented with a large margin.

In there a way to fix this? Or am I doing this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

I realize this was asked long ago, but in the interest of those searching for an answer that doesn't involve runtime mangling...

I'm not keen on it, but you can disable formatting with a (configurable) comment:

```
// @formatter:off
...
// @formatter:on
```

There doesn't appear to be an option for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can leave the source code formatting enabled and use the [`outdent`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/outdent) package to remove the leading spaces from the strings at runtime.